# How to find the provider/extension used to pick a file in UIDocumentPickerViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocumentpickervc

I'm trying to find a way to know which app the user has selected when importing/opening a file in the picker.

*`documentPicker:didPickDocumentAtURL:`* gives a `UIDocumentPickerViewController` object back. I looked in it but no object has the information needed. In *`documentMenu:didPickDocumentPicker:`* there's an NSExtension object in it which contains information only about an Apple extension ("`com.apple.UIKit.fileprovider.default`"), but none about the extension that was actually used to get the file from.

Thank you!

Comment: can u pls explain in detail ? do u want to know the user selction from documentinterac controller ?

Comment: I want to know which app did the user choose his file from. For example if he has both iCloud and Dropbox installed, he can choose a file from either. I want to know which one he used. I'm not talking about the document interaction controller, but on the UIDocumentPickerViewController.

Comment: why don't you use UIDocumentMenuViewController?

Comment: You only know the URL of the file the user picked. The API doesn't tell you the provider/extension.

Comment: @PraWin.S I do. From its delegate I open the UIDocumentPickerViewController.